# React. Pass prop to ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**AS IS**: I animate my components by updating `ref.current.style` properties with the function below. Simply go through `goUpLowerCardAnimation` properties and assign them to `ref.current.style`.

NOTE: Card is functional component.

```
const Card = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return (
        <div>
            Card!
        </div>
    )
});

cardRefs = {
        card_1: React.createRef()
    };

const goUpLowerCardAnimation = {
    top: '0',
    left: '0',
    right: '0',
    transform: 'scale(1)',
    zIndex: '1',
    animationName: 'goUpLowerCard',
    animationTimingFunction: 'ease-in-out',
    animationDuration: '0.7s'
};

animate = (currentRef) => {
        for(let b in goUpLowerCardAnimation) {
            currentRef.current.style[b] = goUpLowerCardAnimation[b];
        }
    };
render() {
    return(
       <Card ref={this.cardRefs['card_1']}>
       </Card> 
    )
}
```

**TO BE**: I don't want to update `ref.current.style` but just send a prop with `goUpLowerCardAnimation` so `Card` component will apply animation based on the prop.

Comment: Have you ever solved this? I'm in the same situation. Thanks

Comment: @Eskel I ended up having all cards in the state, so I could change it and pass data through props: